# Meaning of different softmax notations in papers

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, softmax, attention

I was wondering if the different notations of the softmax input mean different things especially about the size of the output. For example, in the paper [Pointer Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.03134.pdf), it sometimes state the input of the softmax with the subscript j,

[image: Equation with j]

and in another equation, it removed the subscript

[image]

Does the one with the subscript j imply that we produce a distribution over the elements of each ui and the one without the j subscript mean a distribution over all the ui vectors?

I thought it could be a typo, but it happened again in another paper [Reinforcement Learning for Solving the Vehicle Routing Problem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.04240.pdf). Here:

[image]
 [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $a^i_j = \text{softmax}(u^i_j)$ is just an common abuse of notation which should really be written as $a^i_j = \text{softmax}(u^i)_j$, since $u^i$ is the vector which you must compute softmax on, and then you want the $j$th element of the resulting vector. The subscript is then left out of $P(C_i|C_1,\ldots,P) = \text{softmax}(u^i)$ because the LHS is a categorical probability distribution whose parameters are a vector given by the RHS.

I believe the same thing is responsible for the confusion in the second paper, although I haven't read it in detail to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, @shimao. From what you've written, it looks like there is no difference between the equation for $a^i$ (a vector of length $n$) and $P(C_i = j|C_1,\ldots,C_{i-1},\mathcal{P})$ (also of length n). Is this correct?

Comment: Also, what is the novelty, then, of using pointer networks? It looks like they're just using a pair of RNNs in an encoder-decoder framework with the decoder performing additive cross-attention with the each of the encoder hidden states. Moreover, the decoder vocabulary is constrained to be the same as that of the encoder. Is this accurate?